# HTML center text below img tag

Tags: html, css, image, href, center

Here is what I have -

```
<a href="/mi/">
    <img id="i1" name="First" src="1.JPEG" onClick="return goto(this);"></img> 
    First Image 
</a>
```

I am using this piece of code in a loop in my templates to show a bunch of images in a grid (gallery) like fashion. I want to show a one line caption just below all the images.

I want to show "First Image" text (which is a link) right below the `img` tag. I thought since  I am having `<a>` as the parent container the text should be placed below the `<img>` but this is not happening.

How do I show text centered right below my image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .imageLink{
                text-align:center;
            }
            .imageLink img{
                display:block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/mi/" class="imageLink">
            <img id="i1" name="First" src="1.JPEG" onClick="return goto(this);" /> 
            First Image 
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`text-align:center;`and `display:block;`  will do this

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/W242k/)

Answer (score 2):

Make your anchor a block and center text inside of it, then make the image a block so it causes a line break above your text.

```
a { text-align: center; display: block; }
img { display: block; }
```

Also, you don't need a closing image tag, use `<img .. />`

Answer (score -1):

you can wrap the text with

```
<p>First Image </p>
```

tag and this will do the trick ;)

```
<a href="/mi/">
<img id="i1" name="First" src="1.JPEG" onClick="return goto(this);"></img> 
<p>First Image </p>
</a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a block element (`p`) in an inline element (`a`).